# Make a library with cmake that use the SDL

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I am trying to create a library on the top of SDL2. For the compilation I'm using cmake.
First I had this `CMakeLists.txt` for the library :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(SquareEngine)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set (SRCS   Main.cpp
        Rectangle.cpp
        Scene.cpp
        SquareEngine.cpp)

set (HEADERS    Rectangle.hpp
        Scene.hpp
        SquareEngine.hpp
        utils/Color.hpp
        utils/Vector.hpp)

add_library(SquareEngine ${SRCS} ${HEADERS} ${SDL} ${SDL_SRC})
target_link_libraries(SquareEngine ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})
```

To include the SDL2 and SDL2 image I follow [this instructions](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake//).

When I try to build it's work perfectly.

Now I try to use my library in a project. I create my own project and I link my librairy that is located in a subfolder `/SquareEngine` in my project. For the project I use this `CMakeLists.txt`  :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(Demo)


set (SRCS Main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(SquareEngine)
add_executable(Demo ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(Demo PUBLIC SquareEngine)
target_include_directories(Demo PUBLIC SquareEngine)
```

When I try to build the project I got an error like this :
`Cannot open include file: 'SDL.h': No such file or directory`

I try to figure out for long time and I don't have any clue why.

Maybe it will be better to use the SDL in static rather than shared ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the SDL include dirs to the SquareEngine library:

```
target_include_directories(SquareEngine PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Answer (score 0):

The most recent SDL2 releases provide `SDL2::*` CMake targets such that you don't need to fiddle with CMake variables anymore.
So there's no more need to ship your custom `FindSDL2.cmake` and/or `FindSDL2_image.cmake` modules.

With those, you can rewrite your cmake script as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(SquareEngine)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED CONFIG)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED CONFIG)

set (SRCS
    Main.cpp
    Rectangle.cpp
    Scene.cpp
    SquareEngine.cpp
)

set (HEADERS
    Rectangle.hpp
    Scene.hpp
    SquareEngine.hpp
    utils/Color.hpp
    utils/Vector.hpp
)

add_library(SquareEngine ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(SquareEngine PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_image::SDL2_image)
target_include_directories(SquareEngine
    PUBLIC
        $<TARGET_PROPERTY:SDL2::SDL2,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
        $<TARGET_PROPERTY:SDL2_image::SDL2_image,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>
        "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>"
)
```

It can then be used in your game as:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Demo)

set (SRCS Main.cpp)
add_subdirectory(SquareEngine)
add_executable(Demo ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(Demo PUBLIC SquareEngine)
```